# How to handle errors in java Stripes framework?

Tags: java, jsp, error-handling, stripes

I want to handle all the errors including 401,403,404,500,503 in a single error page (.jsp) displaying error code using java stripes framework.I found that in Servlet 3.0 we can handle those using `<error-page>` tag in web.xml.But I want to know is there any better way to handle errors in java stripes framework. 
Is there any ActionBean or Handler to use in this case?
I would be grateful to you if you can suggest any solution..

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways but using the error-page may suit your needs.  See if you can find the Stripes book used, or the pdf:

https://pragprog.com/book/fdstr/stripes